# Не отображается css файл golang

Tags: html, css, golang

при подключении head.css и main.css файлов к index.html отображается только файл head.css. В чем может быть проблема?

**Структура проекта:**

[image: Структура проекта]

**html файл:**

[image: html файл]

**go файл:**

[image: go файл]

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){// функция-обработчик для домашней страницы

    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    ts, err := template.ParseFiles("../static/html/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
        return
    }

    err = ts.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", 500)
    }
}


func main(){
    
    router:=mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", home)

    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css"))


    router.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", fileServer))



    err:=http.ListenAndServe(":8080",router)
    if err!= nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Comment: Решил перенести стили из файла main.css в файл head.css, удалив при этом main.css, но результат тот же. Может ли быть проблема в самом css файле? В браузере отображается все корректно, при запуске сервера  - нет.

Comment: приложите код вместо картинки, пожалуйста. переписывать не хочется

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/B2CFapwzE06 - go файл

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/content.css"> - подключение стилей в html файле (перекинул все стили в файл content.css)

Comment: завтра отвечу на вопрос детально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, как я и думал, проблема таилась в указании неправильного пути к css-файлу. Вот как он должен был выглядеть для моей структуры проекта:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/content.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скринам ты используешь продукт `.IDEA` что-то по типу `phpStorm` Скорее всего там или на уровне движка скрыты какие-то файлы, либо не успели заиндеситься, так что скорее всего смотри в разделе настроек своего редактора... у меня схожие проблемы были с файлами `symfony` моя проблема решилась переименованием имени файла.

Comment: Уже пробовал переименовывать файл, не помогло. Использую GoLand от jb.

Comment: в любом случае это проблема редактора... надо проверить будут ли игнорироваться все файлы этого расширения или только текущий. Возможно где-то добавлено исключение